# Parsing JSON data from Api GET request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, xmlhttprequest, javascript-objects

Im working on a script that gets JSON data from an API call using XHR. So far, im able to get the data and parse the json text into a variable. This variable is returned as an array with multiple objects. Im having issues accessing this objects.

I looked online for similar questions and it seems that the way to access is using the dot/bracket notation together with a for loop to loop thru the array and output the values. However, with my current code, it does not work. My end goal is to use those values from the array and append them to a div. Anyone can point what I'm doing wrong pls?

Code sample:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    let toBeFormated = xmlHttp.responseText;
    let formatted = JSON.parse(toBeFormated);
    //console.log(formatted); UP TO HERE CONSOLE.LOG WORKS
    for (let i = 0; i < formatted.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(formatted.data.length[i]);
    }
}
```

}

This is the sample data from console:
[array output from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRh4u.png)

Comment: Can you provide the `console.log` message as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following `console.log(formatted.data[i]);` instead of `console.log(formatted.data.length[i]);`. Here `formatted.data` is the array. And `formatted.data.length` is a number representing the length of the array.

Comment: TY! "console.log(formatted.data[i]);" works. I shouldn't have use .length as I'm already looping thru the array.length on the for-loop.I'm kind of new to JS so, might be missing part of the concepts.